# Stackify Prefix for Java

Tags: java, stackify

I am trying out Stackify Prefix v3.0.18 to profile a Spring Boot application in WebLogic 12c. The JVM is started with the `stackify-java-apm` agent as per the instructions:

`-javaagent:"C:\Program Files (x86)\StackifyPrefix\java\lib\stackify-java-apm.jar"`

On accessing the Spring Boot Actuator's `/health` endpoint, I do not get anything reported in the Prefix dashboard at http://localhost:2012. Is anything amiss here?

A couple of observations were made; the Prefix agent was trying:

1. To load a properties file from a Linux/Unix path and failed to do so

   `16:16:24.826 [main] WARN com.stackify.apm.config.a - Unable to find properties file /usr/local/stackify/stackify-java-apm/stackify.properties`
2. To write a file into a non-existent directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\Stackify\stackify-java-apm\log\`

I was unable to find an end-to-end demo or tutorial on setting up and using Prefix to profile a Java application.

Comment: Is this already solved? And if yes how? We have the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

I was looking on their support site and it seems that WebLogic 12c is not supported according to this link:

https://support.stackify.com/prefix-enable-java-profiling/

Have you tried submitting a ticket with them?

https://support.stackify.com/submit-a-ticket/

Comment: is it answer the question/